# I want to loop thro owl carousel in wordpress i used this code but nothing works

Tags: slideshow

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="owl-carousel"  id="product-slider">
          <?php while ($loop->have_posts()): $loop->the_post();?>
              <div class="product">
            <?php $loop = new wp_Query(array(
           'post_type' => 'home_producten',
           'orderby' => 'post_id',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            ));?>
           <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) { // check for Image
            the_post_thumbnail();}?>
            <h3 class="title">
            <?php the_title();?>
            </h3>
            <p class="description">
            <?php the_content();?>
            </p>
            <a class="btn btn-warning text-uppercase" href="<?php 
           the_permalink();?>">
            See More
            </a>
         </div>
        <?php endwhile;?>
      </div>
   </div>

 </div>
 <!-- ==== END OF CAROUSEL ===== -->
```

Comment: Can you please share a website link so I can check it and also if you can update slider's js script code here so it is clear understand for everyone.

Comment: Look here , i hope this can help : https://jsfiddle.net/Youssef_X/omfLuk82/15/

Comment: `wp_Query` should be `WP_Query`

Answer (score 0):

> Here you have used dummy images but you can see result. slider is
>   working perfectly. https://www.risingwebstars.com/video.webm
>   Your above code have two mistakes so use below code.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="owl-carousel" id="product-slider">
        <?php $loop = new wp_Query(array(
           'post_type' => 'home_producten',
           'orderby' => 'ID',
            'order' => 'ASC',
        )); ?>
        <?php while ($loop->have_posts()): $loop->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="product">
          <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()){ the_post_thumbnail(); } ?>
          <h3 class="title">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
          </h3>
          <p class="description">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
          </p>
          <a class="btn btn-warning text-uppercase" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> See More </a> </div>
        <?php endwhile;?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

> Use this below script because I have found one problem in this script 
>   [jsfiddle.net/Youssef_X/omfLuk82/15](https://jsfiddle.net/Youssef_X/omfLuk82/15/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  jQuery("#product-slider").owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    items: 3,
    itemsDesktop: [1000, 3],
    itemsDesktopSmall: [979, 2],
    itemsTablet: [768, 2],
    itemsMobile: [650, 1],
    margin: 10,
    nav: true,
    autoPlay: true,
    dots: false,
    autoHeight: false,
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I did exactly what you said but still doesnt work, doesnt show me the slider

Comment: @youssefkhoukhou I understand. Can you please share a website link where you have display the slider so I can check it.

Comment: I just work on my localhost , do you have any way to share it with you ?

Comment: @youssefkhoukhou can you please check in "console" for checking errors display.. this link may help you for that https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/

Comment: do you use visual studio ? i can share the code with you

Comment: @youssefkhoukhou yes please

Comment: Thank you very much Tanmay it works perfect as should be